# Error message in iframes on Web page with many embedded Office documents

Tags: office-web-apps, wiki-pages, iframe

I've tried to embed a large number of PowerPoint files into a web page in `SharePoint 2013`.

As a result, I sometimes get error messages "Sorry, something went wrong..." (see screenshot below).

If I reload the page, other iframes are the ones with the error message and in general the user does have access to all of the linked files.

- Is this a performance problem of the office web applications server?
- Is there a way to embed a larger number of presentations in a web page, or should I avoid this in general?
- If it has to be avoided: is there a way to embed a powerpoint document with at least a preview of the first page?

[image]